# Como percorrer um enum?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Preciso fazer o seguinte: Passar uma `string` e ir percorrendo ela e pegar cada letra encontrada e somar com seu valor correspondente, tipo: a = 1, s = 19 e etc.

Bem, fiz um `enum` com todos os valores da `string`, começando por a = 1 até z = 26 (inclui K,W e Y). Estou com dificuldade de pegar a letra no `for` e acumular seu valor em relação ao `enum`.

```
public enum triaguloLetra
{
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3,
    d = 4,
    e = 5,
    f = 6,
    g = 7,
    h = 8,
    i = 9,
    j = 10,
    k = 11,
    l = 12,
    m = 13,
    n = 14,
    o = 15,
    p = 16,
    q = 17,
    r = 18,
    s = 19,
    t = 20,
    u = 21,
    v = 22, 
    w = 23,
    x = 24,
    y = 25,
    z = 26
}
string teste = "Stackoverflow";
for (int i = 0; i <= teste.Length - 1; i++)
{
    //Como eu digo que teste[i] = ao enum.s?? e assim por diante
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Em vez de um *enum* use um [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dictionary<string, int> valorLetra = new Dictionary<string, int>();

valorLetra.Add("a",1);
.....
....
valorLetra.Add("z",26);

string teste = "Stackoverflow";
int soma = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= teste.Length - 1; i++)
{
    string letra = teste[i].ToString().ToLower();
    soma = soma + valorLetra[letra];
}
```

No entanto, neste caso, não precisa de *enum* nem de *Dictionary*:

```
string teste = "Stackoverflow";
int soma = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= teste.Length - 1; i++)
{
    soma = soma + Char.ToLower(teste[i]) - 'a' + 1;
}
```

Usando LINQ:

```
string teste = "Stackoverflow";
int soma = teste.Select(c => Char.ToLower(c) - 'a' + 1).Sum();
```

Comment: Acho que seria melhor usar um `Dictionary<char, int>` em vez de `Dictionary<string, int>`

Comment: @dcastro Sim, evitaria a chamada a `ToString()`.

Comment: @ramaral, desculpe-me minha ignorância, mas não entendi o 'a' + 1 na lambda acima. Deu certo sem Dictionary<>, mas não entendi o porque de 'a' + 1.

Comment: `char` não é mais que uma instância da estrutura *System.Char* que é usada para representar os caracteres *Unicode* e cujo valor é um inteiro. O valor de 'a' é 97, 'b' é 98 e assim sucessivamente. Com você quer que a sequência comece em 1 teremos que subtrair ao valor de cada letra o valor de 'a' mais 1. Exemplo para a letra 'b' => 98 - 'a'(97) + 1 = 2.

Comment: @ramaral Entendi, ainda que meio estranho. Então "c" seria: => 99 - 'a'(97) + 1 = 3. É isso, certo?

Comment: Exacto. Cada caractere tem um [código](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) associado, é esse código que `char` representa.

Answer (score 7):

Mais uma solução:

```
foreach (var elemento in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TrianguloLetra))) {
    //faz o que você quiser aqui
}
```

Exemplo:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

var soma = 0;
foreach (var elemento in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TrianguloLetra))) soma += (int)elemento;
WriteLine(soma);

public enum TrianguloLetra {
    a = 1, b, c, d,  e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JdS9UM). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/edfyF1). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enum/ScanEnum.cs).

Answer (score 6):

Usando estritamente os pontos da sua pergunta original (*Lookup* em um `Enum`), seu teste deveria ser o seguinte:

```
var valorEnum = (triaguloLetra)Enum.Parse(typeof(triaguloLetra), letra);
```

O método `Enum.Parse` realiza um lookup na coleção de valores do `Enum`, de maneira similar ao *key lookup* de um `Dictionary`, mantendo assim a estrutura original da sua pergunta.

Comment: A minha dúvida crucial, pela sua resposta, foi em não usar e/ou conhecer o Enum.Parse. Aí estava meu quebra-cabeça. Vou refazer dessa forma e ver a resposta e assim, já posso seguir em dois caminhos distintos: O Dictionary<> e o Enum. Valeu.

Comment: @pnet Pois é, os métodos de manipulação de Enum ficam escondidos na classe estática - acho que seria melhor se eles fossem expostos diretamente na instância. De qualquer maneira, mais uma ferramenta pro seu cinto de utilidades. =)

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
public enum triaguloLetra
{
    a = 'a', b = 'b', c = 'c', d = 'd', e = 'e', f = 'f', g = 'g', h = 'h', i = 'i', j = 'j', l = 'l', m = 'm', n = 'n', o = 'o', p = 'p', q = 'q', r = 'r', s = 's', t = 't', u = 'u', v = 'v', x = 'x', z = 'z'
}

var texto = "Stackoverflow";
foreach (var item in texto.ToLower())
{
    var charEnum = (triaguloLetra)item;
}
```

Comment: Entendi Felipe, pegar a letra e transformá-la em um char e como os char são indexados, o valor dos chars já estão implícito. Também seria uma outra forma. Valeu.

Answer (score 4):

Pegando no conselho do @ramaral, uma forma mais funcional de expressar o comportamento do codigo seria:

```
var valores = new Dictionary<char, int>
{
    {'a', 1},
    {'b', 2}
};


int soma = teste.Select(c => Char.ToLower(c))
                .Select(c => valores[c])
                .Sum();
```

Aproveitei para melhorar a sugestao usando um dicionario de `char` em vez de `string`, e usando [collection initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Comment: Ainda esqueço que existe o LINQ. Só falta passar a minúsculas: `c => valores[Char.ToLower(c)]`

Comment: @ramaral Done ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer usando LINQ

```
Func<string, int> Contador = 
    x => 
    x.Select(c => Char.ToLower(c) - 98).Where(c => c > 0 && c < 27).Sum();
```

Exemplo no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LwwlVo)